# probability of at least a fraction of bins contain a fixed number of balls

Tags: probability

Consider the process of throwing m balls into n bins. Each ball is thrown into a uniformly random bin, independent of other balls. What is the probability that at least a constant fraction of bins get a fixed number of balls.